# package org.json does not exist when importing org.json.JSONObject

Tags: java, json, classpath

I am using:

- emacs 24.3.1
- Fedora 20
- jdk1.7.0_45

I have created a Java project using emacs and have the following project and classpath files:

.project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>snaprequest</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

.classpath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
        <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>

    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

I have this version

In my Java program I want to use the JSONObject so I tried to import the following:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

And when I try and compile on the command line I get this error:

```
 error: package org.json does not exist
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

I know I need to add something on my classpath so it can find the jar files, but I am not sure how?

Comment: better to use dependency manager like maven, or google for "how to add external jar in build path eclipse"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Class org.json.JSONObject is available in json-20131018.jar. You need to download this jar and add this jar to your buildpath.

In order to add external jar to buildpath you can 
 - right click on your project in eclipse
 - click build path -> configure build path
 - goto tab libraries
 - there you will find to add external JAR

This will allow you to include any external jar into your build path.

Comment: Actually I am not using eclipse I am using emacs. I was thinking there was a way to edit my .classpath so that when I use javac it will check the classpath and find the jar files that I need. I have downloaded json-simple-1.1.1.jar and need to use that in my project. Thanks.

Comment: @MLProgrammer-CiM WHat to do next after adding this dependency in pom.xml ?

Comment: This is working for me. I got this json-20131018.jar file from this URL. https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.json/json/20131018/source-code

Answer (score 17):

In my case i was using maven build tool and got this error so had to add below dependency from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) like below and error resolved.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20180130</version>
</dependency>
```